# jQuery validation plugin not validating form in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, iframe

I am using this plugin:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

To validate a form that is hosted on a different server from my development site.  All the validation scripts are on that document and appear to be working fine.

http://forms.icis.com/content/CHX0041_RequestFreeTrial

I am using an iframe to pull in the form from the external site but when i try and submit the form and fire the validation script it is not working.  It just submits the form as if there was no validation at all.

The iframe sits within a CMS page that is contained in another form so i thought the issue may be there.  This fiddle demonstrates the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/We78c/

**EDIT**

It seems as though removing the URL paramaters from the iframe src fixes the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/We78c/2/

However i need them so as to pass them through to some hidden input variables in the child iframe.  Is this a known issue?

Comment: Does the validation work on the iframe source page? I went to the source page in the jsFiddle you gave and I didn't get any validation.

Comment: Yes the iframe source page is linked to in the question and that is the point of my question, that the fiddle gives no validation when it should and the source page does.

Comment: I'm saying that the source page does not do any validation either (for me).

Comment: As per my edit.  It seems as though the URL parameters are causing this.

Comment: Ok thanks. However it seems that the iframe form does the validation for me (tested on both Firefox and IE8).

Comment: It really is not working for me with URL parameters here: http://forms.icis.com/content/CHX0041_RequestFreeTrial?mode=icispricing&product=pricing&channel=chemicals&commodity=ethylene&commodityregion=asia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a JS error causing this to fail the validation.  Commented out and seems to be working now.

Comment: I just encountered a similar problem. I found `$('#description').val()` was causing errors when used from within the `submitHandler(form){..}` block. The fix for me was to use `form.description.value` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your form you're setting the method="#" and action="post". The method should be method="post" and action should be the url where you're posting.

Comment: Agreed sorry.  Updated fiddle here but this does not fix the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/We78c/1/

Comment: I went to the source page of the form: http://forms.icis.com/content/CHX0041_RequestFreeTrial?mode=$$Cta-Mode$$&amp;product=$$Cta-Product$$&amp;channel=$$channel$$&amp;commodity=$$commodity$$&amp;commodityregion=$$region$$ and there is no validation happening there.